# switch between multiple versions of software

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I am using `update-alternatives` to configure multiple versions of software installed on my machine.

The software has multiple executables A, B and C. To switch between versions I need to install and configure each executable individually.

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/A A /path/to/version1.0/bin/A 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/B B /path/to/version1.0/bin/B 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/C C /path/to/version1.0/bin/C 1
```

How can I alternate between multiple installed versions of a set executables on Linux?

I would rather specify the path with the folder:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ App /path/to/version1.0/bin/ 1
```

So I only select which version to use. This fails to create a link because /usr/bin is a directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t link a set of binaries from a directory, but you can cause multiple alternatives to be related:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/A A /path/to/version1.0/bin/A 1 \
  --slave /usr/bin/B B /path/to/version1.0/bin/B \
  --slave /usr/bin/C C /path/to/version1.0/bin/C
```

The secondary alternatives aren’t weighted since their selection depends only on the primary’s selection. Switching the alternative for `A` will switch the alternatives for `B` and `C` to match.

You could list all the binaries in `/path/to/versionX/bin` and build the appropriate command line to automatically extend this to all the binaries...

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 3 options.

- Just use the one that you want, by using a full path when you use it.
- the update-alternatives as you are using, or in other answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526569/4778
- do your own sym-links see below.

Set up some directories, with files

- `mystuff/A/bin1`
- `mystuff/A/bin2`
- `mystuff/A/bin3`
- `mystuff/B/bin1`
- `mystuff/B/bin2`
- `mystuff/B/bin3`
- `mystuff/active → mystuff/A` (or B)

Then use update-alternatives to point to `mystuff/active`

You can then switch by updating one sym-link.